# Object State validation based on Controller Actions in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: validation, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to implement a DRY based validation using `IValidatableObject` in an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC application. I'm using both data annotations to validate "format" rules, and `Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)` method to implement my business rules.

So far, it's working smoothly, now, I have some extra business rules based on Object State, which will control some kind of workflow of my Objects, and that workflow will depend on the controller action to be executed.

I want to avoid adding business rules in my controller and want to centralize any validation within my Model. I'm wondering if there's any standard way to do it, otherwise I'll implement my own mechanism.

For example:

Trying to Delete MyObject with STATUS_1 should give a validation error...

This is MyObject class:

```
public class MyObject : IValidatableObject
{
    public MyObjectState State { get; set; }
    
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
    public decimal Value{ get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        //My custom model validation here
    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> ValidateState(ActionExecutedContext actionContext)
    {
        var controllerActionDescriptor = actionContext.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
        if (controllerActionDescriptor.ActionName == "Delete" && State != MyObjectState.STATE_1)
            yield return new ValidationResult("You cannot delete if STATE_1");
    }
}
```

These may be the possible MyObject statuses:

```
public enum MyObjectState
{
    STATE_1 = 1,
    STATE_2 = 2,
    STATE_3 = 3
}
```

This may be MyObject Controller with Delete Action:

```
public class MyObjectController: Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public MyObjectController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var myObject = await _context.MyObject.FindAsync(id);
        var validationStateResult = myObject.ValidateState(null);
        //Not sure how to provide the action context here
        if (!validationStateResult)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index)).WithWarning("ALERT: ", validationStateResult.ToString());
        }

        return View(myObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax in view,action return errormessage or MyObject to ajax,and ajax will alert errormessage or redirect to delete Page.In controller,you can get actionName to check.Here is a demo worked:

MyObject ValidateState(I change the `ActionName` to DeleteCheck,and you can use ActionName to check ):

```
 public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> ValidateState(string ActionName)
    {
      
        if (ActionName == "DeleteCheck" && State == MyObjectState.STATE_1)
            yield return new ValidationResult("You cannot delete if STATE_1");
    }
```

MyObjectsController(You can get actionName with `RouteData.Values["action"]`):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteCheck(int? id)
            {
                if (id == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
             
                var myObject = await _context.MyObjects.FindAsync(id);
                var action =(string)RouteData.Values["action"];
                var validationStateResult = myObject.ValidateState(action);
                string messages = string.Join("", myObject.ValidateState(action)
                             .SelectMany(x => x.ErrorMessage));
                TempData["Message"] = messages;
                if (messages!=null&&messages != "")
                {
                    return Json(messages);
                }
   
                return Json(myObject);
            }
            public IActionResult Delete(MyObject myObject) {
                return View(myObject);
            }
```

View:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="delete1(@item.Id)" >Delete</a>

    function delete1(id) {
         
            $.ajax({
                method: 'get',
                url: "MyObjects/DeleteCheck?Id=" + id,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (typeof data === 'object') {
                        window.location.href = "/MyObjects/Delete?Id=" + data.id + "&&State=" + data.state + "&&Price=" + data.price;
                        //alert("object");  
                    } else {
                        alert(data)
                    }
                     
                }
            });
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Hi Yiyi You, thanks for your response, although this is not quite the approach I was looking for, I was able to resolve it by using var action = (string)RouteData.Values["action"]; that way I can definitely implement a mechanism in my model. Thanks!!